# Voiceflow not seeing HTTP POST request handler's response data

Tags: php, http

I have a simple PHP http POST request handler (HANDLER below).
When I make a request to it with my own php file (REQUESTOR below), it succeeds and gets the returned status, message and data items that the HANDLER sends.  (REQUESTOR OUTPUT below).
However, when I call the handler using VoiceFlow's API step, it succeeds, but the response does not contain the status, message and data items (see VOICEFLOW RESPONSE DISPLAY).
Why not?

HANDLER

```
<?php

// Check if the request method is POST
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    // Validate any necessary parameters
    // For example, check if required fields are present

    // Handle authentication (if required)
    // For example, validate API keys or OAuth tokens

    // Process the request
    $postData = $_POST; // Get the POST data
    // Perform any necessary processing or validation

    // Generate response
    $response = array(
        "status" => "success!",
        "message" => "Request processed successfully",
        "data" => $postData // Return any data as needed
    );

    // Send JSON response
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // Handle other request methods (optional)
    http_response_code(405); // Method Not Allowed
    echo "This endpoint only accepts POST requests.";
}

?>
```

REQUESTOR

```
<?php
// URL of the PHP handler that processes the POST request
$handlerUrl = 'http://easy-street-2.local/ee/postRequestHandler.php';

// Data to be sent in the POST request
$postData = array(
    'username' => 'john',
    'password' => 'password123'
);

// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// Set cURL options for the POST request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $handlerUrl);         // Set the URL to which the request will be sent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);               // Set the request method to POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    // Set the data to be sent in the POST request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     // Set to return the response as a string rather than outputting it directly

// Execute cURL request and get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if ($response === false) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch); // Output error message if the request fails
} else {
    // Output the response
    echo 'Response: ' . $response; // Output the response from the handler
}

// Close cURL session
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

REQUESTOR OUTPUT

```
Response: {"status":"success","message":"Request processed successfully","data":{"username":"john","password":"password123"}}
```

VOICEFLOW RESPONSE DISPLAY  (no status, message nor data included. why?)

```
{
 "VF_STATUS_CODE": 200,
 "VF_HEADERS": {
  "connection": "close",
  "content-encoding": "gzip",
  "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
  "date": "Fri, 01 Mar 2024 19:28:44 GMT",
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
  "x-powered-by": "PHP/8.1.23"
 }
}
```

Voiceflow API step setup

[image: Voiceflow API step setup]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I was using my the php file that I was using to test/make the request as the endpoint in for the API step.  It was not the endpoint.  It called the endpoint, and echoed the result, which is why it looked so much like I was actually calling endpoint - same basic result came back.
DUH!